# How to differentiate e to a function?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of $$\large e^{2 \pi i t \sin(\pi/(2t))}.$$

I know that I am to take the derivative of the exponent, and then multiply it by the beginning problem - the piece that is giving me trouble is the $i$, I think.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: $i$ is just another constant.

Comment: Does $\pi/2t$ mean $\frac{\pi}{2t}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}t$ (in other words, $\pi/(2t)$ or $(\pi/2)t$)?

Comment: Sorry - pi/(2t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule, $$\frac{d}{dt}e^{u}=\frac{du}{dt}e^{u}$$
You have $u=2\pi it \sin(\pi/2t)$, so by the product rule $$\frac{du}{dt}=2\pi i \sin(\pi/2t)+2\pi i t \frac{d}{dt}\sin(\pi/2t)$$
Now for this derivative, let $v=\frac{\pi}{2t}$ so $\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{\pi}{2t^{2}}$. Use the chain rule to get $$\frac{d}{dt}\sin(v)=\cos(v)\frac{dv}{dt}=\cos(\pi/2t)\cdot \frac{-\pi}{2t^{2}}$$
Substituting back in gives
$$\frac{du}{dt}=2\pi i \sin(\pi/2t)-2\pi i t \cos(\pi/2t)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2t^{2}}$$
Therefore
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{2\pi i t \sin(\pi/2t)}=2\pi i \left(\sin(\pi/2t)-\frac{\pi}{2t}\cos(\pi/2t)\right)e^{2\pi i t \sin(\pi/2t)}$$

Comment: Oh dear. $\pi/2t$ meant $\frac{\pi}{2}t$, didn't it?

Comment: No, it meant pi/(2t).

Comment: That's alright then!

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate complex functions the same way you would with real functions.  Treat $i$ as a constant.

Comment: But why? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: That is not the function given in the question.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks, fixed